# If $\mathbb{k}$ is a division ring then $\mathbb{k}^n$ is a simple $M_n(\mathbb{k})$ module

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, division-ring

**Problem:** If $\mathbb{k}$ is a division ring then $\mathbb{k}^n$ is a simple $M_n(\mathbb{k})$ module

I'm lost on this problem, the hint is to use linear algebra but i dont see how it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** : First try to see that it's enough to show "for any nonzero vector $v$, there is $M\in M_n(\mathbb k)$ with $Mv = (1,0,...,0)$".

Then try to prove that, using a nonzero coordinate of $v$ and the fact that $\mathbb k $ is a division ring.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. The nonzero coordinate of $v$ would be used to prove the first claim

Comment: I misinterpreted: I though that "that" referred to the original statement rather than the claim.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : ah, sorry if it was unclear then !